# Mocha test runner : How to exclude a child directory when recursively running tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

So i have a folder structure like below -

- common:

  - lib
  - components
  - support

I am using mocha cli options to run tests in all sub directories of Common folder recursively using below command:

`BABEL_ENV=test mocha common --recursive --reporter dot --require test.js --timeout 2000 --exit`

What i want is, mocha to exclude the **support** folder while running.

What i have tried,

- Individually mention all sub directories except support in the command
  `BABEL_ENV=test mocha common/components common/lib --recursive --reporter dot --require test.js --timeout 2000 --exit` which seems to work.
- Tried to use exclude and ignore option, **but this doesn't seems to work**,
  `BABEL_ENV=test mocha common --exclude common/support --recursive --reporter dot --require test.js --timeout 2000 --exit`

Any suggestion, how to exclude/ignore support folder while still recursively running tests in all sub-directories of common folder.